# Unknown database error after creating it (sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm getting the next error while trying to run my Flask app:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1049, "Unknown database '/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/app2.db'")
```

so it seems like there is no database.. but I ran the next scripts using sqlalchemy_utils and everything was ok:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql://root:@localhost/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/app2.db")

create_database(engine.url)
```

but still I get the error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused MySQL, a database server, with SQLite, a database in a file.  You created a SQLite file, but are trying to tell MySQL to connect to it, which makes no sense.

Use the `sqlite` dialect in the connection string.

You can avoid typing the whole path (and tying the app to that path) by pointing to the file relative to the app's location.

```
import os
db_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'app2.db'))
engine = create_engine('sqlite://{}'.format(db_path))
```

Consider using [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/) rather than trying to manage the database yourself.